# Swift get decimal value for String characters

Tags: swift, character, decimal

Is it possible to get the decimal value for String characters in Swift?

something like:

```
let words:String = "1 ring to rule them all"
var value:Int = 0

for i in 0..<words.count {
    let char = words[words.index(words.startIndex,offsetBy:i)]
    value += Int(char.decimal)
}
```

where the first character in "1 ring to rule them all" is 49. Possible?

Comment: If there are multiple digits in the string (`"12 rings to rule them all"`, or even `"1 2 3 4 5"`), are you looking for the sum of each digit parsed separately? Or a different behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to get the ASCII (or Unicode) character code of each of the characters?

Comment: I need to get the decimal value for each character in a string. Decimal values like you find here: https://www.charset.org/utf-8/69

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
let words = "1 ring to rule them all"
var value: Int = 0

for i in 0..<words.count {
    let char = words[words.index(words.startIndex,offsetBy:i)]
    if let val = char.asciiValue {
        print("----> char: \(char)  val: \(val)") // char and its "decimal" value
        value += Int(val)
    }
}
print("\n----> value: \(value) \n") // meaningless total value
```

Comment: thank you, but that only works for ascii characters. "蜇", 34567, is nil.

Comment: @Alexander, yes the Unicode values in decimal for each char in a string.

such as: 9992

let airplane = Unicode.Scalar(9992)!
print(airplane)


Prints "✈︎"

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks like this is the way:

```
let characterString = "蜇"
let scalars = characterString.unicodeScalars
let ui32:UInt32 = scalars[scalars.startIndex].value
```

Comment: Note, you might consider adding all of the Unicode scalars, not just the first one, so that it can distinguish between characters that share the same first Unicode scalar (e.g., ‍♂️ and ‍♀️).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add up the Unicode values associated with a string, it would be:

```swift
var value = 0

for character in string {
    for scalar in character.unicodeScalars {
        value += Int(scalar.value)
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```swift
let value = string
    .flatMap { $0.unicodeScalars }
    .compactMap { $0.value }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

---

While the above adds the values, as requested, if you are trying to get a numeric representation for a string, you might consider using `hashValue`, or checksum, or CRC, or the like. Simply summing the values will not be able to detect, for example, character transpositions. It just depends upon your use-case for this numeric representation of your string.